# Pattern of light formed when a wire is placed in front of a laser

Tags: visible-light, laser, double-slit-experiment

I'm a high-school student. I recently recreated the double slit experiment myself with the help of a laser pointer, using wire and black tape to create the two slits.

When disassembling the apparatus, I had taken off the two pieces of tape, with the wire still mounted in front of the laser, I fired the laser. I noticed a line perfect red line form (perpendicular to the wire) with the dot of the laser in the middle form on my wall.

Upon closer examination of the line, I noticed, within the line, uniform regions of high and low intensity light alternating.

I don't understand why exactly I can observe such a formation of light. The internet wasn't very helpful, and neither were my teachers.

I have attached the images of my apparatus and light formation. In the first image, the blue arrows indicate the straight lines I was mentioning (which formed perpendicular to the wire). The green arrow marks a line of light I can only observe through my camera. (I assume it's  infrared light).

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: I can invent answers, but ruling things out by experiment would be nice too. You could, for example, rule out reflection off the wire by painting it black ...

Comment: Is the 'line' aligned with the wire, or perpendicular to it?

Comment: If the wire was "horizontal" in the picture then this might be due to [Babinet's principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babinet%27s_principle)  If not, I'm not sure.  It would be helpful if you edited your question to add that information.

Comment: @catalogue_number The wire was perpendicular to the lines.

Comment: Single slit (or single wire) diffraction is a thing.

Comment: As an experimentalist, you need to show the pattern you expect (the FT of the aperture, or under Babinet's Principle:  1 - the obstruction). You also need some control shapes that come out as expected so we know the set up is good.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71Rp-jG6Eek

Comment: It's quite clearly babinet's principle, and if you give us the exact measurements (distance to the wall, distance of fringes) the equation will hold. The interesting thing here is the perpendicular (horizontal) fringe, and I think it's due to the curve of the wire.

Comment: Babinet's Principle, for sure.   See also  Spot of Arago.  (not as a solution  but as additional "cool things" that happen with diffraction)

Answer (score 2):

I’m going out on a limb to say that the vertical lines are [edge diffraction](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/020/05/0389-0400). Could also be Babinet’s principle, which in this case is essentially the same thing. Basically, you don’t need slits for diffraction; it happens whenever a wave encounters any object with features on the scale of the spatial coherence. Given the size of the wire, and the grazing incidence of the light at the edge, your setup certainly qualifies. Your horizontal edges will diffract light vertically, which is what we see.

Now, about the horizontal line, pretty much any vertically oriented edge that the beam encounters will diffraction it horizontally. That edge could come from the way you’ve attached the wire, or perhaps it could be inherent to the laser. Does the horizontal line persist if you remove the wire? If not, can you experiment with the wire positioning to see whether you can change the position/shape/brightness of the horizontal line?

Comment: Changing the position of the wire seems to change the distance between the little points on the on the vertical line. Another thing I notice is that, when the image is formed around 5cm - 3cm from the laser, I can observe the vertical line diverge into multiple lines and curve, on the ends. 

I haven't been able to change the intensity or brightness as with anything I try, as far as I can see.